# preg_match validation

Tags: php, validation, preg-match

I have a form and upon submitting it, I would like to ensure the following:

1. the beginning of whatever is typed in the input field starts with `mod_`
2. After `mod_`, only alpha numeric characters can be used.

For the first stage, I got this far:

```
if (preg_match('/^mod_/', $str)) {
        //script goes here
}
```

However for the second stage, I'm not entirely sure if is the best method/works:

```
if (preg_match('/^mod_/[A-Za-z0-9]$/', $str)) {
        //script goes here
}
```

I have probably made a mistake in the second stage of the `preg_match()`, however, if I haven't, could someone please let me know if what I have used is ok, else what could be done to improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
if (preg_match('/^mod_[A-Za-z0-9]+$/', $str)) {
```

The `+` that I added before the `$` means "match the previous thing 1 or more times."  In this case, that is 1 or more ASCII characters or digits.

Comment: +1, thank you for the code and explanation. I'll accept when it allows me ;)